# Unicode literals causing invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, unicode-literals

The following code:

```
s = s.replace(u"&", u"&amp;")
```

is causing an error in python:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

removing the `u`'s before the `"` fixes the problem, but this should work as is? I'm using Python 3.1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `u` is no longer used in Python 3. String literals are unicode by default. See [What's New in Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit).

> You can no longer use `u"..."` literals for Unicode text. However, you must use `b"..."` literals for binary data.

Answer (score 3):

On Python 3, strings are unicode. There is no need to (and as you've discovered, you can't) put a `u` before the string literal to designate unicode.

Instead, you have to put a `b` before a byte literal to designate that it *isn't* unicode.

Answer (score 1):

In Python3.3+ unicode literal is valid again, see [What’s New In Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.3.html#summary-release-highlights):

> New syntax features:
>
> New yield from expression for generator delegation.
>   **The u'unicode' syntax is accepted again for str objects.**